# How to set a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in a project managed by docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-oauth

How to set you `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in your project managed by docker-compose?
What to add to your `docker-compose.yml` to do so?

I first tried to put my crediential path in `docker-compose.yml` this way:

```
services:
  flask_app:
    container_name: flask_app
    image: dockerhub-flask_live_app:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /path/to/my/local/folder/keyfile.json
```

Spoiler alert, that doesn't work...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer and I think it could benefit everyone!

[Here is where I found it.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/archived/cloud-run-local-dev-docker-compose/index.md)

The idea is to create a temp key file in 'volumes' that you will reference in the 'environment'. And voila!

```yaml
services:
  flask_app:
    container_name: flask_app
    image: dockerhub-flask_live_app:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      # https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/keys/keyfile.json
    volumes:
      # Inject your specific service account keyfile into the container at runtime.
      - /path/to/my/local/folder/keyfile.json:/tmp/keys/keyfile.json:ro
```